# How do you consolidate different accounts if you've migrated the main account to GitHub login?

Tags: support, login, github

I mainly use Stack Overflow but have migrated my log in to GitHub on that account. The issue is that I can't now log in to the other accounts that in the past were associated (via email login I presume)- I have 27 accounts in total across various communities.

( [Let us sign in with GitHub](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340877/let-us-sign-in-with-github-on-all-stack-exchange-sites-not-only-stack-overflow) asks for GitHub login to be implemented across all communities but doesn't answer the question merely explains why GitHub is not site wide. [How to change my login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-login-providers) is a hint to the answer but doesn't directly answer the question as it explains how to add a log in. If for example, follow that answer and add GitHub as your login then you precisely have the problem this question is seeking to answer. The comment below suggests [this as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) )

If I try to log in to them there is no GitHub option. So the only way is to create an account using one of the other options. But then this account is not tied back to the original Stack Overflow account as the credentials don't match.

**Original:**
Stack Overflow - login via gazzer@example.com (no longer used)

Bicycles  - ditto

Ask Ubuntu - ditto

**New:**
Stack Overflow - login via GitHub

Bicycles  - login via gazzer@example.com

Ask Ubuntu - login via gazzer@example.com

When I migrated SO to GitHub I had no idea that the other accounts would not be too, and that they wouldn't have GitHub authentication anyway.

Since I posed this question, I think I have an answer (which I'll post below), but there are two issues here. The usability and confusion with the above situation should be addressed I believe.

Also, there is probably a significant number of people who don't want to use Facebook or Google for privacy (perceived or real) reasons. What are their options?

[After attempts to edit the question be so as not to be marked as a duplicate, I'll post the solution here since I cannot answer this question and neither of the above answers quite work, I can't see how the question can be make only more different than the above questions than it already is:

if GitHub is your *only* authentication method. i.e. like me you have removed email authentication, then the easiest way seems to be to *add* a [Google or Facebook login to your primary account using this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-login-providers) and then go to your other accounts, and login via Google/Facebook. These I believe are the only logins that work across all communities and thus you cannot log in site wide with just a Github login].

Comment: After 12 years, I also still find new features and/or behaviors of SO/SE. Some are weird, some are annoying, but that's how the site(s) worked from the beginning. This one is just one of those: GitHub sign in works only on SO.

Comment: Try logging in on multiple accounts on the same computer, but to different sites in the network. I eventually got that working at one point on one computer, no idea how - _do not touch my cookies_.

Comment: The irony was that this question was moved to StackExchange (which I couldn't log into as was the topic of my question). Then it was locked because a totally different feature request also had the word 'GitHub' in it.

Comment: Don't edit the answer into the question, write an answer; you are allowed to answer your own question, unless it's closed - in this case you should accept that or ask for it to be reopened.

Comment: The edited banner, in the 2nd link, points to this URL: [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or Google / Facebook / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/282094), which answers this question.

Comment: That solution from 13 years ago basically says: "Contact support"