# Can't log in to other communities. Only on SO (GitHub account)

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, login, user-accounts, github

I'm able to log in with a GitHub account on SO (Stack Overflow). When I go to other communities I see this:

[image]

When I try to log in, I don't see an option to use GitHub:

[image]

I think this is a **bug**, because I bookmarked some questions on these communities (I don't use them very often), and it is impossible that every question is suddenly deleted and I don't have any action for two years. Also to bookmark new questions, i.e., on *[Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/tour)* I need to log in first, so I am **unable to use these sites with my account**.

I used only this way **(log in to SO with GitHub and then go to another community if needed)** in the past, because I don't have a Google or Facebook account with this email. Also, it is visible from pictures that I have 101 reputation, so I should be able to add comment or upvote, but I'm not able to do anything.

Currently, I'm using a Google account to post this question on SE. Is it possible to connect my current SO account with the Google account, or something else to be able to use all accounts on SE I created previously?

This scenario is similar to this answer: [can't log in to Super User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381682/1277431)

Comment: @RobertLongson So this means that I must use new account on every community except on SO (until someone removes github login because it is not used by programmers)?

Comment: You can have more than one login on your account, then you can use github on Stack Overflow and something else for the rest.

Comment: Thank you @RobertLongson. I will try this and edit question if needed.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm able to solve my problem using the wa you suggested. You can move it to answer.