# Why can't I sign up for some Stack Exchange sites using GitHub?

Tags: support, login, github

Why are some of the communities not compatible with GitHub? How do I make sure I'm using the same account when creating new accounts if they don't have the GitHub option?

Comment: Duplicate of [Let us sign in with GitHub on all Stack Exchange sites, not only Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340877/let-us-sign-in-with-github-on-all-stack-exchange-sites-not-only-stack-overflow) and [Can't log in to other communities. Only on SO (GitHub account)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383356/348196). See [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1278658).